# Syntastic and C

Tags: vim, syntastic

I installed gcc, clang, and make. None of them appear in `:SyntasticInfo` as available checkers.

```
Syntastic version: 3.7.0-129 (Vim 704, Linux)
Info for filetype:
Global mode: active
Filetype  is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: -
Currently enabled checkers: -
The current file will not be checked (file not readable / not local)
```

Settings from my `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:syntastic_c_compiler =['gcc', 'clang','make']
let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options ='-Wpedantic -g'
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

Comment: It says `Info for filetype:` but no filetype. What does it say when you have a `.c` file loaded so you are using filetype `c`?

Comment: Aside from what @DanLowe said above, your config doesn't make sense.  `g:syntastic_c_compiler` is supposed to be either `gcc` or `clang`, not a list.  You probably also want to set `g:syntastic_c_checkers` to something meaningful.  Read the manual to find out what that might be.